# Are there any way to do following using Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, arrays

On my HTML Website;
When user Click on `#seasons > div:nth-child(1) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(1)` This Element I need to run function `myFunc(S1E1x,S1E1y,S1E1z);`

So When user Click on `#seasons > div:nth-child(1) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(2)` This Element I need to run function `myFunc(S1E2x,S1E2y,S1E2z);`

When user Click on `#seasons > div:nth-child(5) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(10)` This Element I need to run function `myFunc(S5E10x,S5E10y,S5E10z);`

As Common Term, When someone Click on `#seasons > div:nth-child(p) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(q)` This Element I need to run function `myFunc(SpEqx,SpEqy,SpEqz);`

Are there any short way to do this. Currently I manually add `onclick="myFunc(SpEqx,SpEqy,SpEqz)"` to all `#seasons > div:nth-child(p) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(q)`.

Please Help Me!!!

Comment: Please add your source code to this question, so we can help you.

Comment: you need to use index...  jQuery("#seasons > div:nth-child(p) > div.se-a > ul > li:nth-child(q)").index() will return you the index of the element, which will be an integer, starts with 0 for first element. So add 1 to that index, you will get the nth element index

Comment: How are these elements generated? There is very likely ways to simplify this knowing how they are created

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing that changes depends on the index of the `<li>` child in its container, so making it DRY isn't hard - but you have another problem, you're using tons of standalone variables instead of a more sensible data structure, making dynamic access difficult. Use an array instead. For example, instead of a function call like

```
myFunc(S5E10x,S5E10y,S5E10z)
```

Use a single array of arrays of objects instead:

```
// corresponds to season 5, episode 10: remember, arrays are 0-indexed
const { x, y, z } = SE[4][9];
myFunc(x, y, z);
```

So the big SE array will look something like

```
[
  // S1
  [
    // E1
    {
      x: <value of S1E1x>,
      y: <value of S1E1y>,
      z: <value of S1E1z>,
    },
    // E2
    // etc
```

Then, use event delegation to watch for clicks. On click, identify the index of the clicked `<li>` in the parent `<ul>` to find the episode index, and the index of the clicked season in the parent `#seasons` to find the season index. Then just look up the match in the SE array:

```
const seasons = document.querySelector('#seasons');
seasons.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;

  // only process clicks on an episode `<li>`:
  if (!target.matches('li')) return;

  const seasonParent = target.closest('#seasons > div');
  const seasonIndex = [...seasonParent.children].indexOf(seasonParent);

  const episodeParent = target.parentElement;
  const episodeIndex = [...episodeParent.children].indexOf(target);

  const { x, y, z } = SE[seasonIndex][episodeIndex];
  myFunc(x, y, z);
});
```